# How to sum up rows based on condition in tableau?

Tags: tableau-api, calculated-columns, tableau-desktop

I have created a table that looks like this[image]

The table shows that of all orders that has a valid flag of 1, number of orders corresponding to different "Before Prefr Unit Price". I want to sum up all the counts of non-zero "Before Prefr Unit Price". That is, something like this:
[image]
Can anyone help me out?